# How to disable ajax animation for the the 'Add to Cart' button of products grid in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, phtml

I try to save Ajax for the the 'Add to Cart' button. But to remove the class and title changes during the addition of the product.
Example: when I put "Add to cart" - all time see "Add to cart", not "Adding...".

Comment: You mean you want to remove "Adding...." text while add to cart ?

Comment: I try to disable the replacement of the title and class.
title="Add To Cart" class="action tocart primary"

Answer (score 0):

Copy `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml` to `app\design\frontend\Vendor\default\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml`
Make changes:

```
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
        }
    }
    </script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
        "catalogAddToCart": {
            "addToCartButtonSelector": "",
            "addToCartButtonDisabledClass": ""
        }
    }
}
</script>
```